# Bow or lazy checkmate?

Tags: optimization, chess, checkerboard

Suppose that both players cooperate, find the shortest, in terms of number of moves, black checkmate such that the game is valid and white pieces never go on rows 4 to 8.

e.g. `1. e3` is valid while `1. e4` is not (a pawn went to row 4).

We search for a black checkmate, i.e. whites must win!

Comment: So black checkmate = white wins?

Comment: @Stevo yes, sort of, because whites can also win if black resigns, which is not wanted here!

Answer (score 10):

> 4.5 is doable, see the checkmate position below.

> [image: mate position with king moved to middle of board]
>  `1. e3   e6`
>  `2. b3   Ke7`
>  `3. Nh3  Kf6`
>  `4. Bb2+ Kf5`
>  `5. Bd3#`

Answer (score 5):

This seems to fit the criteria as far as I understand it (with white winning):

> I can get it into 6.5 moves: [image: Chess game]

Why optimal path?

> Not neccassary optimal though. 1 move mate, 2 move mate, and 3 move mate are all not going to work. I don't know about 4,5 or 6 move mates, however in this scenario the king has to walk to the other side of the board